# accessing functions between two (2) movieclip inside a nested movieclip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, function

ok im a noob for AS3 since i just started, i have two (2) movieclips inside a movieclip, the main mc is called main_mc then the two movieclips inside named trigger_mc and move_mc, trigger_mc has the instance name of start_ani, then inside the timeline of main_mc i have this code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

start_ani.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, correctans);

function correctans(e:MouseEvent):void {
    move_mc.animate();
}
```

then i created a motion as actionscript 3.0 using move_mc then i inserted the code inside the timeline of the move_mc itself, and i made a function for that motion called animate, my problem is how do i access a function between two movieclips which both are inside another movieclip, i know this method is not programming wise, but i kinda need to learn this, pls help me, i badly need this, thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with 'a function between two movieclips'?

Comment: well, thers a functions inside one of the movieclips inside the main movieclips, the i want to trigger the function inside move_mc which by clicking trigger_mc.

Comment: Can you not do something like `this.parent().move_mc.animate()`?

Comment: tried it sir, but it gives me this error "TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.", do i need to use class on this one?..

Comment: Added some more ideas to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Parent is a property, not a function - you don't need ():

```
this.parent.move_mc.animate();
```

Also, you didn't mention the instance name of the move_mc movieclip, but access like the above requires the instance name to be move_mc - the movieclip symbol name doesn't matter in actionscript.

**Update 1:** To clarify, you said:  **trigger_mc has the instance name of start_ani**

Good, then this code will work:

```
start_ani.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, correctans);
```

But you didn't say:  **move_mc has the instance name of ???**

So we don't know if this code will work:

```
function correctans(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ???.animate();
}
```

Fill in those ??? for one.

**Update 2:**  do you know if the click handler is being fired?  Why not add a trace statement?

```
function correctans(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("got click event!");
    ???.animate();
}
```

Because for a CLICK event, you need:

```
start_ani.buttonMode = true;
```

Though as you say, this isn't good programming practice because this assumes those two movieclips are siblings of the same parent.  It's not extensible.  If they're not, your code could throw errors.  Just keep that in mind.

Comment: oops..sorry..my mistake..anyway your answer made the error go away, but still doesnt trigger the function animate..but still thank you so much for your advice and answer.. i appreciate it alot..gonna still try to solve this..

Comment: @user2689301 ...What is the body of your function?  It's probably a problem with your code in the function.

Comment: @user2689301, I tried to clarify my answer wrt instance names.